# which jar contains HttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java

Which jar contains `HttpClientConnectionManager`? I need the jar's name to configure `pom.xml` of maven.

I seached that the jar is `org.apache.httpcomponents`, then I configured `pom.xml` as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

It shows the error:

```
HttpClientConnectionManager cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try a different version of dependency. I am using the below dependency and it is working for me.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.5</version>
```